# Dynamic SQL Server Nested EXEC

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to EXEC a stored procedure inside an nvarchar that I a them executing. 
I receive the following error,  `Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure Map.AdminServiceLoad, Line 127 [Batch Start Line 2]
Could not find stored procedure ''.`

The stored procedures I am referencing exist, I had re-started MSSQL, am I unable to EXEC with an EXEC ?

```
DECLARE @NewStoredProc nvarchar(max) = '
create procedure [Map].[Load'+@TableName+']
    as
    begin
        DECLARE @MapTable nvarchar(100) = [Map].['+@TableName+']
        DECALRE @MapDevlTable nvarchar(100) = [MapDevl].['+@TableName+']
        DECLARE @ShapesAreValid bit
        DECLARE @PointsAreValid bit

        EXEC @ShapesAreValid = Map.AdminServiceValidateShapes @TableName = @MapDevlTable
        EXEC @PointsAreValid = Map.AdminServiceValidatePoints @TableName = @MapDevlTable

        if(@ShapesAreValid = 1 and @PointsAreValid = 1)
            begin
                INSERT INTO [Map].['+@TableName+'] SELECT('+@ColsToLoad+') FROM [MapDevl].['+@TableName+']
            end
    end
'
EXEC @NewStoredProc
return 1
```

Comment: You will get this error precisely when `@NewStoredProc` is `NULL`. Always `PRINT` dynamic strings before attempting to `EXEC` them. Note that this will *not* execute a stored procedure, it will *create* one. To execute the newly created stored procedure, you'll need to use either another dynamic `EXEC` or (simpler) `sp_executesql`. Or, you know, just don't create a procedure at all and just execute these statements directly.

Comment: Your dynamic SQL statement is not executing a stored procedure, it's creating one.

Comment: The fact that you have a return statement here leads me to think that you are creating a stored procedure full of dynamic sql that creates a stored procedure. This is almost always a sign of a design that is less than ideal.

Answer (score 2):

It would need to be EXEC(@cmd) not EXEC @cmd.

Without the parentheses it looks to find a stored procedure with the same name as the string inside @cmd.